# How do you create rate schedules in AnyLogic for the Road Traffic Library?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, traffic-simulation

I am using AnyLogic Personal Learning Edition on Ubuntu Linux, and I am making a road traffic simulation.
I'd like to have a lot of traffic at the start of the simulation, and have it linearly decrease over time.

So I tried to change the **Arrivals defined by** to *Rate Schedule*, but when I click on the *Rate Schedule* field, it shows a blank. And if I run it anyway, an error pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and configure a [Schedule](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/data/schedule.html) block. It'll appear in the Car Source's Rate Schedule drop down menu once created.

Comment: My table in the _Schedule_ properties is blank. See [link](https://u.cubeupload.com/lovecodeabc/Screenshotfrom202305.png)